# How to sync Facebook events in Google calendar, but only those I'm going

Tags: facebook, google-calendar, synchronization, facebook-events

So, yeah, I'm able to add Facebook events to my Google calendar following this: https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178/

The only problem is that it adds every event I've been invited to. I just want a way to add those I've RVSP GOING (and Maybe too if possible).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible by default as it is at the moment.

Some time ago, I stumbled upon [this nifty site](http://eventcal.flown.io/) (which I am in no way affiliated with) that creates a new calendar-link you can use: http://eventcal.flown.io/

As the developer writes

> Right know it simply removes events you have not responded to yet as you probably won't attend them.

This was my solution, it works fine for me. But its not a solution, it's a workaround, as Facebook by default (sadly) do not allow the functionality you are looking for